# ¿Por qué la descarga del archivo se bloquea hasta que cierro la página?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, google-chrome, navegador-web

Lo siguiente me sucede al actualizar una pagina en Localhost:

Estoy accediendo a archivos **HTML/JS** en localhost servidos por **Node**. Cuando actualizo el código, Webpack reconstruye automáticamente los archivos **JS**.

A veces, cuando actualizo la página, la descarga del archivo **JS** se bloquea para siempre. Sospecho que esto se debe a que actualicé mientras el archivo aún se estaba construyendo. Todavía se bloquea después de:

- Actualizar
- Abrir el archivo **JS** directamente
- Abriendo el **HTML** en una pestaña separada
- Reiniciando el servidor de Node
- Esperando el tiempo suficiente para que el archivo definitivamente terminara de reconstruirse

Necesito cerrar la pestaña original para poder acceder al archivo nuevamente.

Ocurre también cuando Devtools está abierto.

Las únicas formas que he encontrado para evitar que se bloquee son:

- Cerrando la pestaña original
- Ir a la raíz del localhost (http://localhost/)

Estoy usando la versión **88** de **Chrome** en **Windows 10**. Creo que esto es causado por Chrome y no por Node, ya que reiniciar el servidor de Node no hizo nada. ¿Hay alguna manera de no tener que cerrar y volver a abrir la pestaña cada vez?

Lo anterior siempre es en el archivo JS principal.